# "system is computationally singular" error in mlogit R-package

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial

I wanna solve my problem using multinomial logistic regression, `mlogit` R-package.

when I run the below code,

```
ml.data <- mlogit.data(dat, shape = "wide", choice = "Resp")
mlogit(Resp ~ A + B+ C+ D, ml.data)
```

I am getting this error: "system is computationally singular".
I saw [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76488/error-system-is-computationally-singular-when-running-a-glm), but it does not help.
I appreciated if anyone could help me.

Comment: Check out this post for an idea of the problem: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32585/singularity-issues-in-multinomial-model-using-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mlogit` doesn't follow the same model command-line formulas as other models.

Try

```
mlogit(Resp ~ 1|A+B+C+D , ml.data)
```

and compare to

```
multinom(Resp ~ A+B+C+D , dat)
```

in package `nnet`.  Also, check out `?mFormula` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521937/error-in-mlogit-error-in-solve-defaulth-gfixed-system-is-computationall)