# system is computationally singular : mlogit

Tags: r, mlogit

When I am trying to add all variables in formula, I am getting this error. If I omit A then, the model runs fine.

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Choice = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L), A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L), 
    C = c(1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L), F = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, -1L), Alternative = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
> model = mlogit( Choice ~ A + B + C + D + E + F | 0, data = df1, 
+                
+                alt.var = 'Alternative', 
+                
+                shape = "long")
Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 4.85723e-17
```

I have seen these two questions and the documentation however still not able to figure it out completely. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[R mlogit model, computationally singular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29849640/r-mlogit-model-computationally-singular)

[Error in mlogit: Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 3.4767e-18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521937/error-in-mlogit-error-in-solve-defaulth-gfixed-system-is-computationall)

Comment: If you one-hot-encoded the variables A through F, then you do need to leave one out on the right hand side of the regression equation. The omitted variable serves as the reference value.

Comment: Ok I see. You are right.